# What are the easiest ways to obtain gems in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

What are some of the easier ways to get gems in Clash Royale other than purchasing them?

I've seen different strategies on YouTube but I want expert advice as to which strategy is the easiest.

Comment: What do you mean by easiest? Lowest time investment? Lowest cost? Lowest complexity?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is of course getting them from chests, but if you don't want to have only a 0-4 gem increment (some chests don't have gems) then you could participate in free-entry challenges(If you are good enough). Usually once per three weeks, a gem challenge will appear. If you reach enough wins, you could get up to 100 gems!

Comment: You could also use daily quest refreshes to get quests that reward gems